# MSP430 JTAG, read flash content / Chip ID

Tags: flash, msp430, jtag

I am very new to MSP430 programming, I only have experience with Atmels AtMega and the Atmel Studio.

In Atmel Studio I have the possibility to read the Chip ID, and Flash.
How can I accomplish this with the MSP430? I am using CCS at the moment, and can't see any method.

I have a commercial hardware, where a MSP430F2252 is used, I would like to try if the chip is accessible via JTAG, and if it is, I would like to read out the content, if it is not, I would like to erase the whole chip and write a new program for that.

Is this somehow possible with CCS or another Software?

Thanks!

Comment: on Linux, take a look at mspdebug.

Comment: First off, it sounds like you may need to first identify where on the board they may have included a header, or holes where a header may be added, that provide a simpler connection for the purpose. Also, one document I quickly found is [MSP430 Programming With the JTAG Interface](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau320ah/slau320ah.pdf). There, you will find inconsistencies also mentioned that you may need to consider, as well. If the chip is removable, you could place it into a demo board that TI sells which may hold that chip and allow more direct use with software.

Comment: Hello, 
I have access to the JTAG Pins on the board, I've already identified them. I also know how to theoretically program a new MSP430, but the problem I have is, how to communicate with an already programmed one. And with a maybe blown security fuse.